# How to read data from a Vector

Tags: c++

How can I use the following vector to read true/false from using a while or for loop.
With this implemtation of the loop I get an error for the oprator `!=`

> no operator "!=" matches these operands

```
vector<bool> Verification;

Verification.push_back(true);
Verification.push_back(false);
Verification.push_back(true);
Verification.push_back(false);
Verification.push_back(true);

for (int it = Verification.begin(); it != Verification.end(); it++) {   
                    if (it==true) cout<<"true";
                    else if (it == false) cout<<"false";
}
```

Comment: *it, an iterator itself is not true or false it points to an element of the container that may be true or false, also your iterator shouldnt be an int

Comment: `int it = Verification.begin()` should be a compile error too.

Comment: I don't think the error is the operator. You are declaring `it` as `int` but trying to put an `iterator` in it. Change `int` to `vector<bool>::iterator`. Although, personally I prefer this style- `for(size_t i = 0; i < vector_name.size(); i++)`

Comment: Aside: `*it==true` is the same as `*it`, is the same as `(*it == true) == true`. Just use the `bool` value directly

Comment: @AbdurRakib that does look a lot better but what do I check for true or false in that for loop

Comment: Also `it` is `iterator`. Kinda like pointer. So, change `it==true` to `*it==true`.

Comment: Side note: I find range based for loops easier to work with: `for (auto b : Verification) { ... }`

Comment: @AbdurRakib in this case it is not, OP declared it as an `int`

Comment: With `size_t` it's far easier to loop without error. Simply `vector_name[i]` will give the value at `i` index.

Comment: Read the introduction to iterators in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring `it` as the wrong type. The result of `Verification.begin()` is a `std::vector<bool>::iterator`. But you don't need to specify that.

Use a [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop instead

```
for (bool b : Verification) 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer works great, side question what does bool b : Verification do

Comment: @Omar click on that blue link `range-for` and everything will be clear

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to iterate over an `std::vector`

1. Using iterator

Long example:

```
for( std::vector<bool>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it ) std::cout << *it;
```

or the same but shorter:

```
for( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it ) std::cout << *it;
```

2. Using index

Here:

```
for( unsigned int i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i ) std::cout << v[i];
```

3. Range loop

Here:

```
for( bool b : v ) std::cout << b;
```

(there are some more but we will omit them for clarity)

Looks like you mixed 1 and 2 hense you have compilation errors. Choose one.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that `Verification.begin()` gives you an **iterator** while `it` is an `int`.

To **solve** this you could modify your for loop to:

```
for (std::vector<bool>::iterator it = Verification.begin(); it != Verification.end(); it++) {   
                    if (*it==true) cout<<"true";
                    else if (*it == false) cout<<"false";
}
```

Note `*it` means we're dereferencing the iterator `it` and then comparing the result.

Also you don't need the `else if` because you can just use `else`.

#### Alternative solution

You can also use a range-base for loop as shown below:

```
for (bool element : Verification) 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << element;
}
```